# Unable to loop back when using natatime

Tags: perl

I have a array from which I am taking 7 elements at a time, using the function `natatime` from `List::MoreUtils`. They are all positive integers between 0 and 62 in no specific order and are random.

```
my @attn_range = (0, 39, 21, 17, 62, 43, 62,
                  1, 40, 22, 16, 60, 41, 59,
                  2, 41, 23, 15, 58, 39, 56,
                  3, 42, 24, 14, 56, 37, 53,
                  4, 43, 25, 13, 54, 35, 50,
                  5, 44, 26, 12, 52, 33, 47,
                  6, 45, 27, 11, 50, 31, 44,
                  7, 46, 28, 10, 48, 29, 41,
                  ....                         
                  62, 23, 33, 45, 62, 39, 59);
our $it = List::MoreUtils::natatime(7, @attn_range);
while (1) {
    while (my @vals = $it->()){
        for my $i (0 .. $#vals){
            print "Port$i: $vals[$i], ";
        }
        print "\n";
 }
```

However, I was expecting to cycle through back from the top when the end of list is reached, but this method doesn't do that.

Can you help me? I desire to loop back to the top at when the last 7 is read and printed inside my `while (1)` loop.

*(in my example I created an array `@attn_range` above, but in reality the values in my array are read from a .csv file and @attn_range array is very large and a multiple of 7. I used `natatime` because i found it to be easy, any way can be adopted to take 7 elements from my array.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to "reset" the iterator returned by `natatime`: you need to simply create a new iterator each time the outer `while` is executed

And don't use `our` unless you have a very good reason to do so

This version of your code should work, but beware that it will run endlessly as it stands because there is no exit from the outer `while`

```
while () {

    my $iter = List::MoreUtils::natatime(7, @attn_range);
    
    while ( my @vals = $iter->() ) {

        for my $i ( 0 .. $#vals ) {
            printf "Port%d: %d, ", $i, $vals[$i];
            ...
        }
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

---

#### Update

Now that I'm back at a proper keyboard I can offer something that I hope is more useful

It's wasteful to create a seven-element iterator over and over again, and I would prefer to copy the data into an array of seven-element arrays

This code shows the idea, and also uses `join` together with `map` to produce the output that you describe in your question. Each seven-item chunk is available within the `for` loop as `@$group`, and its elements are `$group->[0]` through to `$group->[6]`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @attn_range = (
      0, 39, 21, 17, 62, 43, 62,
      1, 40, 22, 16, 60, 41, 59,
      2, 41, 23, 15, 58, 39, 56,
      3, 42, 24, 14, 56, 37, 53,
      4, 43, 25, 13, 54, 35, 50,
      5, 44, 26, 12, 52, 33, 47,
      6, 45, 27, 11, 50, 31, 44,
      7, 46, 28, 10, 48, 29, 41,
     62, 23, 33, 45, 62, 39, 59,
);

my @groups;
{
    for ( my $i = 0; $i < @attn_range; $i += 7 ) {
        push @groups, [ @attn_range[ $i .. $i+6 ] ];
    }
}

while () {

    for my $group ( @groups ) {
        say join ', ', map {
            sprintf 'Port%d: %2d', $_, $group->[$_];
        } 0 .. $#$group;
    }

    exit;  # For testing
}
```

Comment: Nice. Yes, I want it to run endlessly... thanks! I see my mistake now. Thank-you for shining the light.

Comment: Thanks,. I like the second update using map and join way better. It helps to learn those as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the solutions in the earlier answer, the following solutions don't require `@attn_range` to have a multiple of 7 elements:

```
sub make_cyclic_natatime {
   my ($n, @list) = @_;
   die if !@list;
   my $i = -1;
   return sub {
       return map { $list[++$i % @list] } 1..$n;
   };
}

my $iter = make_cyclic_natatime(7, @attn_range);
while (1) {
    my @vals = $iter->();
    say join ', ', map { "Port$i: $vals[$i]" } 0..$#vals;
    select(undef, undef, undef, 0.100);
}
```

Or just

```
die if !@attn_range;
my $i = -1;
while (1) {
    my @vals = map { $attn_range[++$i % @attn_range] } 1..7;
    say join ', ', map { "Port$i: $vals[$i]" } 0..$#vals;
    select(undef, undef, undef, 0.100);
}
```

The downside is these solutions won't be as fast as the earlier answer's second solution.